# Automatically cite all author names instead of "et al." on first occurrence?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, natbib

I am using BibTeX and Natbib (author-year) for citing references in my document. Whenever there are three authors or more for a given paper, the citation will be "First author et al. (year)". This is the way I would like it to be in general.

However, when the paper is cited for the first time in a document, I would like all the names to appear, ie "First author, second author, and third author (year)". I know I can achieve this manually by `\cite*`. But is there also a way to have this done automatically on the first occurrence?

Comment: Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the package option `longnamesfirst` to achieve that, i.e.,

```
\usepackage[longnamesfirst]{natbib}
```