# Editing BibTeX stylefile from Biometrics Journal to accommodate their requirements

Tags: bibtex, citing, natbib

For submitting a paper, the references need to be in the following format:

> References in the text should be ordered by author's surname and
>   publication date. In publications by three authors, all are listed the
>   first time, and et al. used subsequently. For four or more authors, et
>   al. is used throughout. In the list of references at the end of the
>   paper, authors should be listed alphabetically by last name. For
>   references with more than six (6) authors, only the first six (6)
>   authors should be listed, followed by "et al." Journal titles should
>   be complete and not abbreviated. Careful attention should be given to
>   the format used in recent issues.

Source: http://www.biometrics.tibs.org/directions.html#references

The journal provides a documentclass and a BibTeX stylefile that can be downloaded from
http://www.biometrics.tibs.org/biomlatex.zip

However, the stylefile does not do the following things:

- In publications by three authors, all are listed the first time, and et al. used subsequently.
- For references with more than six (6) authors, only the first six (6) authors should be listed, followed by "et al."

---

From different posts ([here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/121189/automatically-cite-all-author-names-instead-of-et-al-on-first-occurrence) and [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26575/bibtex-how-can-i-automatically-reduce-long-author-lists-to-xxx-et-al)) I know that the first point can be automatically achieved by using the `longnamesfirst` option of the `natbib` package. However, as the provided `biom` documentclass automatically loads the `natbib` package, I can't set the `longnamesfirst` option (even if I use `\PassOptionsToPackage{longnamesfirst}{natbib}` it won't work and I don't know why). However the `longnamesfirst` option can be loaded by editing the `biom` documentclass but I can't see an option that allows me to use longnamesfirst only when there are up to 3 authors.

The second point can be done by rewriting the following function from the provided .bst file (see http://www.biometrics.tibs.org/biom.bst.txt), however, I don't know what exactly I have to change in this function.

```
FUNCTION {format.names}
{ 's :=
  #1 'nameptr :=
  s num.names$ 'numnames :=
  numnames 'namesleft :=
    { namesleft #0 > }
    { s nameptr "{vv~}{ll}{, jj}{, f.}" format.name$ 't :=   
      nameptr #1 >
        { namesleft #1 >
            { ", " * t * }
            { numnames #2 >
                    { "," * }
                    'skip$
              if$
              t "others" =
                { " et~al." * }
                { " and " * t * }
              if$
            }
          if$
        }
        't
      if$
      nameptr #1 + 'nameptr :=
      namesleft #1 - 'namesleft :=
    }
  while$
}
```

Here is a minimal working example of a .tex file that illustrates the two issues mentioned above (you need the files from http://www.biometrics.tibs.org/biomlatex.zip to compile the following code):

```
\documentclass[usenatbib, referee]{biom}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\title[Title]{Title}

\author{Author$^{*}$\email{email@address.com} \\
       Institute of the Author, Postal Code, State
       }

\begin{filecontents}{report.bib}
@Article{hatzis2011genomic,
  Title                    = {{A Genomic Predictor of Response and Survival Following Taxane-anthracycline Chemotherapy for Invasive Breast Cancer}},
  Author                   = {Hatzis, Christos and Pusztai, Lajos and Valero, Vicente and Booser, Daniel J and Esserman, Laura and Lluch, Ana and Vidaurre, Tatiana and Holmes, Frankie and Souchon, Eduardo and Wang, Hongkun and others},
  Journal                  = {Journal of the American Medical Association},
  Year                     = {2011},
  Pages                    = {1873--1881},
  Volume                   = {305},
}

@Article{Pepe2008,
  Title                    = {{Comments on 'Evaluating the Added Predictive Ability of a New Marker: From Area Under the ROC Curve to Reclassification and Beyond' by M. J. Pencina et al., Statistics in Medicine (DOI: 10.1002/sim.2929)}},
  Author                   = {Pepe, M S and Feng, Z and Gu, J W},
  Journal                  = {Statistics in Medicine},
  Year                     = {2008},
  Pages                    = {173--181},
  Volume                   = {27},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}

\begin{abstract}
Abstact
\end{abstract}

\begin{keywords}
Keywords
\end{keywords}

\maketitle
Two examples that do not work with the provided .bst files:
\begin{itemize}
\item In the reference list of \citep{hatzis2011genomic}, the first 10 authors are listed and not the first 6 as required by the journal.
\item The citation of \citep{Pepe2008} shows only `Pepe et al.', however, the journal requires that `publications by three authors, all are listed the first time, and et al. used subsequently.'
\end{itemize}

\bibliographystyle{biom} \bibliography{report}

\end{document}
```

This yields the following pdf:
[image]

Could someone please help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If they provide a `bst` file which does not aplly to their requirements, *they* should fix the `bst` file.

Comment: I see your point and you are right, but I am not sure if I am making something wrong or if the stylefile is not making what they request.

Comment: Then ask them. Your example code looks ok and if it doesn't give the requested output it is their responsability to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and was able to make it work by editing the bib entry such that it shows only the first 6 authors and then says "and others", like this:
author={Lavine, Joel E and Schwimmer, Jeffrey B and Van Natta, Mark L and Molleston, Jean P and Murray, Karen F and Rosenthal, Philip and others}

Comment: Welcome to tex.sx.